# Including xml attribute when the value is the same as the default

Tags: .net, xml, xsd, xmlserializer

i have an xsd we use with the XMLSerializer class in .net to generte an xml document. We have the following type with a default value

```
  <xs:complexType name="telephoneType">
<xs:simpleContent>
  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
    <xs:attribute name="type" default="BH">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="BH"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="AH"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="mobile"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
```

It seems like when we set the value to BH which is the default it does not include the attribute in the document. is there a way to always include these?

Comment: This is kind of optimization. So either you remove default attribute for type or handle the default case in the xml receiving side.

Comment: we unfortunately have no control over the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

The serialiser will not create the element/attribute when the property is equal to its default value. There is going to be little to do unless you create a custom method to serialize your objects.

Comment: so there is no way to override this behaviour?

Comment: No, you would need to create a customer serializer/deserializer. Why is it important that you include the value anyway?

Comment: Because the receiving end is out of our control and they often expect a value for an attribute. Ideally it would be good to show the attribute despite the value.

Comment: Sounds like they are enforcing a non-standard approach on you, which is a pity. Unfortunately, the custom serialization is going to be the only option.

Comment: I think we might have to remove the default property of the attribute

Comment: actually that still didn't work. i'm wondering if XmlAttributeOverrides might work