# Why does an optional element that has the same value as the default in the schema not show up in a transaction?

Tags: xml, xsd

I use various xml transactions for request and then response transactions.  The response transaction echoes the request transaction and then provides any "hit" information.  I've noticed that when I try to display the echo, if an element was optional and has the same value as the one provided in the default, then it is omitted.

```
<Request Name="Marty Jones" Education="0"/>
```

On Request, if 'Name' is required and 'Education' is optional, with an enumeration of (0 - none, 1 - high school, 2 - college) and the default is "0".  The element above will display as:

```
<Request Name="Marty Jones"/>
```

If I specify that Education="2", then it will display as:

```
<Request Name="Marty Jones" Education="2"/>
```

Is there a reason that the optional, defaulted value is omitted?  I want to show the entire echo no matter what the conditions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many XSD-aware tools will do this when writing XML.  The idea is that it makes the XML shorter and more readable if values that equal the default are omitted (provided they are optional).  For example, for XSD itself, any values of `minOccurs="1"` or `maxOccurs="1"` will be omitted when writing it out - imagine how cluttered your XSD would be with them included on every `<element>`, `<sequence>`, `<choice>` etc that they could be.

Note that when parsing with an XSD, a defaulted value and an explicit value equal to the default are not distinguished - without this information, the tool cannot reconstruct which was originally used.

However, not everyone wants this behaviour in every application; so some tools have a configuration switch to turn this off. As this whole issue is not part of the XSD spec, any such configuration switch is tool-dependent. So you'll have to tell us which tool you're using.

BTW: Here's a question on this issue, with links to other questions on specific tools. (e.g. MarkLogic has a switch):

[Does the Xml Schema spec define the serialization of optional attributes with a default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246810/does-the-xml-schema-spec-define-the-serialization-of-optional-attributes-with-a)

Comment: Thanks 13ren!  The application in question is written in C# in VS2010.  For years, I used custom COM components to read, write, and validate the XML.  I was returning the entire echo regardless of usage or a default value.  I've been using the XML functionality in .NET and this seems to be an issue where I can't provide the client with what they had in the past without changing the schema.  I'd like to be able to configure my XML to show all of the attributes, even if they are optional and match the default value.

Comment: I meant edit your question to state what tool you're using - BTW also add tags for it.  Because then, your question will be seen by people who know that tool. Few people will see your comment down here stating your tool (and it doesn't help to tell me, because unfortunately, I don't know C#).  But now that you've accepted my answer, people will be less likely to look at your question... You might be better off asking a new question, that is specifically about C# (but search SO first - you might get an instant answer that way!)

Comment: I'll just paste your comment into your question for you, so it will be there now - you can edit it for clarity.

Comment: er... I thought about it, and I think I shouldn't edit your question in this way, so I've reverted it. It was too interfering of me - sorry!

Comment: no worries!  I will start another thread and see if I can keep the attributes in question from being omitted (based on using .NET VS2010).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your schema, and you haven't explained what processing you are doing.

If you validate the given XML through a schema that defines a default value for the attribute, then the "post schema validation infoset" for the document will contain the defaulted value. From the evidence provided, either you haven't done the validation, or what you are displaying is not the PSVI.

Answer (score 0):

attribute declaration has "use" property which can take value of "required" however it won't work with "default". In short you want something like below but is not valid.

```
<attribute name="Education" default="0" use="required/>
```

In short you cannot assign default and make the attribute mandatory.